# Ввод массива в цикле for

Tags: java

Как в *Java* ввести массив через цикл `for`?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String[] a = new String[3];

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
            a[i] = reader.readLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
            System.out.printf("%d: %s\n", i, a[i]);
    }
}
```